# _sleep() is not working in C++

Tags: c++, sleep

I was trying to write simple code, but whenever I call the function `_sleep()` it doesn't work. I have tried it in two different projects now, and every time I use it, it gives me an error that says:1

> '_sleep': This function or variable has been superseded by newer library or operating system functionality. Consider using Sleep instead. See online help for details.

I tried so much other stuff like `Sleep()`, `sleep()` and just a bunch of other random junk that didn't end up working. If there another command that will pause the console for a certain time, that I can change how I want, and that doesn't pop up with some ugly thing like `"Press any key to continue..."`, or a fix to my command, please let me know!

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int rouletteGen();

int main()
{
    //--------
    //| Idea |
    //--------
    //cout << box 1 << box 2 << endl;

    int wheel, a, b, c, time, cA, cB, cC;

roulette:
    while (a >= 1)
    {
        cout << "          _|_" << endl;
        cout << "          \|/" << endl;
        cout << "_______ _______ _______" << endl;
        cout << "|     | |     | |     |" << endl;
        cout << "|  "<< cA <<"  | |  "<< cB<<"  | |  "<< cC<<"   |" << endl;
        cout << "|     | |     | |     |" << endl;
        cout << "_______ _______ _______" << endl;

        _sleep(250);
        while (b >= 1)
        {
            cout << "_|_" << endl;
            cout << "\|/" << endl;
            _sleep(250);
            while (c >= 15)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

int rouletteGen()
 {
    int dice;
    srand(time(NULL));
    dice = rand() % 3;

    dice = dice + 1;

    return dice;
}
```

Comment: What OS and compiler?

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ - different languages!

Comment: Do you have access to C++11 features?

Comment: It literally tells you what to do. So, if you have read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx , what was the problem you had with using `Sleep` ? It works just as documented. I suspect the problem is elsewhere too though, e.g. the useless `while (c >= 15)` loop that's using an uninitialized variable. However, you need to tell us the exact problem you have, and not rant about unrelated things.

Comment: Im using Visual Studio and It has nothing to do with the while loop because I already fixed that I just posted the code when I was in the middle of coding it so it wasn't perfect. And it just says that Sleep is not a command!

Comment: *"I tried so much other stuff like Sleep(), sleep() and just a bunch other random junk that didn't end up working"*.  How exactly didn't it work?  Show that code and the associated error message.

Comment: Please don't "just post the code while I was in the middle of coding it".  Take the time to remove all the extraneous stuff as a courtesy to all the people who are going to take the time to look at your problem and help you solve it.

Comment: If this is the real code `a` is not initialized so `while ( a >= 1) {` may never enter the loop as a result `_sleep(250);` may never execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sleep() function is different in various OS as it is being implemented by the OS libraries.
If you are using windows the best way is #include the windows.h header file,
then where you want to use sleep function use it as **Sleep(time_in_ms)**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
int main(){
std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
Sleep(3000);
std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have access to C++11 or higher I would use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and let the standard library worry about calling the correct "sleep" function.

Answer (score 1):

To use `Sleep` you need to `#include <windows.h>`.  The better solution in my view is to suppress that warning. `_sleep` works just fine.

Comment: Its not a warning its a error and it wont let me run it, also my finished code wont run it just goes straight to "press any key to continue..." then closes.

Comment: OK, either you have the compiler error - or you don't.  If you do, you can't run the program.  If you don't have the compiler error and the program is not behaving as you want, you have a different problem, and should ask a separate question.

Comment: Is a > 1? There is no initialization in the code provided so it may never get to the _sleep().

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure it's normally a warning - but you may well have "warnings as errors" set (which is a *good* thing).  You can still disable the  message.  Google  "C4782" or whatever the error number is.