# _sleep() function not working

Tags: c++

I get the error:

> '_sleep': This function or variable has been superceded by newer
>   library or operating system functionality. Consider using Sleep
>   instead. See online help for details.

Can you guys and/or girls tell me what library is causing this error?

Code:

```
// A program to keep track of points and time and to give a random letter for the game scattergories
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::getline;

void ltr()    //gives a random letter
{
    srand(time(NULL));    //gives a differant pattern every time
    char letter;
    letter = rand() % 27 + 64;         //assigns a random letter in ascii code to a char (resulting in a random letter)
    cout << "The letter is " << letter << "\n";
}

void timer()
{
    cout << "You got 1.5 minutes to finish\n";
    for (int i = 90; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            cout << i << "\n";
        _sleep(1000);
    }
    cout << "DING DONG!!! DING DONG!!! Time's up!!!\n";
}

void table()
{
    int plr, ctr;
    string lst[5][20];           //first dimantion: how many players. second dimantion: how many catagories, third dimantion(if added) will be the round
    cin >> plr >> ctr;       //parameters for later
    cin.ignore();                  //To avoid the "getline" reading the last input
    for (int x = 0; x<plr; x++)       //the player changes only after the previus player finishes
    {
        timer();
        for (int i = 0; i<ctr; i++)        //changing catagory
        {
            getline(cin, lst[x][i]);
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << "Next player\n";
    }
    for (int x = 0; x<plr; x++)                   //this part (the whole "for" loop) is for confirming
    {
        cout << "Player number " << x + 1 << ": ";
        for (int i = 0; i<ctr; i++)
        {
            cout << lst[x][i] << "    ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    _sleep(5000);
}

int points()        //points per round
{
    int a, b, c, sum;
    cout << "How many sections only you got?\n";          //worth 15 points
    cin >> a;
    cout << "How many words only you got?\n";       //worth 10 points
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many words you and another person got?\n";    //worth 5 points
    cin >> c;
    sum = a * 15 + b * 10 + c * 5;
    return sum;           //Note: It doesn't matter how many sections there are.
}

int act()
{
    int Points;
    ltr();
    table();
    Points = points();
    cout << "You have earned " << Points << " this round\n\n";
    return Points;
}

int main()
{
    int Points;
    cout << "Starting in five seconds\n";
    _sleep(5000);
    Points = act();
    for (;;)          //inf loop
    {
        int ph;
        cout << "Press 1 to continue or anything else to stop\n";
        cin >> ph;
        if (ph == 1)
        {
            Points += act();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "You have earned a total of " << Points << " great job!";
    _sleep(5000);       //time to read the last text
    return 0;
}

/* To do list:
  *Convert to arduino
  *Make timer work in background of of table
  *Check if words in the table (for differant players) are the same and give points accordingly
  *Check if words are actual words (connect an online dictonary?)
  *Make interface? (if possible and I have time to learn how)
  *Think of what to do with Hardwear
  *Comment rest of the code
*/
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear to you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The message is clear, I want to know what library is causing it and how to fix it

Comment: There's no library that causes this. The cause is in the program shown. And the error message tells you exactly what to do to fix the shown code. Again: what part of "replace _sleep() with sleep()", which is what the error message tells you to do, you were unable to understand?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that gives the error message: _'Sleep': identifier not found_

Comment: @Sela12: Then the real is question is "Sleep() function not working", not "_sleep() function not working". Not that it would make a very good question, honestly. You can find the answer in 10 seconds by googling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\_sleep() is not working - c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948371/sleep-is-not-working-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using `Sleep()` function you need

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Doesn't that make the program not portable?

Comment: @Sela12: It was not portable to begin with. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for for portable sleeping.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Because of the "stdafx.h"?

Comment: @Sela12: And also because of `_sleep`, which is not standard C++.

Comment: @ChristianHackl is there a standard C++ sleep function?

Comment: @Sela12: Did you actually read my comment?!

Comment: @ChristianHackl yeah, my bad. I can't get the 'sleep_for' to work

Comment: @Sela12: Everyone here, including your compiler (!), has told you precisely what's wrong and how to fix it. It is extremely unclear what problem is left.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I got the `sleep_for` to work, thanks